# How do I uninstall Java

Tags: java

I'm a beginner on ubuntu. Not very technical either. I am trying to remotely connect to a remote workstation, on 1 page it reads that I have java 8.25 but the next page seems like it ain't picking it up for some reason. I am advised by my technical team to uninstall java. I followed a few form guides but it seems confusing. Can you let me know the steps basics?

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Could you please add output for two commands to your question: `namei $(which java)` and `update-alternatives --list java`. This will help to understand how did you install your java

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall the existing Java version 8.25, you can execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-8-jre
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-8-jre-lib
```

To install the Java V8 again,

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Hope this helps.